# Incorrect launch image size

Tags: ios, xcode

Using Xcode 6.3.1, I tried to submit an app to the App Store and it was rejected saying that I needed to provide a launch image size of 320x568 for iPhone 5. The `images.xcassets` section requires 6 images. What sizes are required for each of the images?

I have looked at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html), but it does not give a satisfactory answer.

Comment: your link was close: check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1 instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can view the required `launch image` sizes under the **Attributes inspector**.

[image: launchImages]

[**Fullscreen**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5s0g.gif)

This shows all the `launch images` available for a universal application that supports both portrait and landscape. The minimum amount of `launch images` required for you to submit your application to the App Store can be seen [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1).

Comment: Why does your example show ten different targets, and my Launchimage section only shows three?

Comment: This is a good answer and explains how to find out the sizes of the images in xcassets, but does not explain which ones are required to submit an application to App Store.

Answer (score 0):

I use `640×960` and `640×1136` in xcode 6.3.1